# React table misaligns table header columns with table row columns

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why my header and body rows aren't in sync. I'm using semantic ui for the css.  Is it because my body rows are rendered in a different component?  I tried moving them all to 1 and it didn't make any difference.

```
<table className="ui celled table" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >Status</th>
        <th >Service Date of Visit</th>
        <th >Claim ID</th>
        <th >Insurance Plan</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


        <tbody>
         {this.state.claims.map ( claim => <ClaimRow claim= { claim } /> ) }
    </tbody>
```

and inside the component.

```
const ClaimRow = ( {claim} =this.props ) =>  (


    <Form.Field>
      <tr >
         <td >
              <input type="radio" name={claim._id} label="That Was Me"  value="valid" checked={claim.status === 'valid'} />
               Valid? <br />
              <input type="radio" name={claim._id} label="Looks Like Fraud" value="fraud" checked={claim.status === 'fraud'} />
              Fraud? <br />
              <input type="radio" name={claim._id} label="Looks Like Fraud"  value="notselected" checked={!claim.status && "defaultchecked"} />
              Not Yet Sure
          </td>
        <td >  {claim.claimDate}  {claim.status}</td>
        <td >  {claim.claimID}  </td>
        <td >  {claim.carrier}  </td>
     </tr>
   </Form.Field>

);

ClaimRow.propTypes = {
  claim: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default
```

and the table footer

```
        <tfoot className="full-width">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
          <div className="ui small button">
            Approve
          </div>
          <div className="ui small button">
            Approve All
          </div>
          <div className="ui right floated button" >
              Next
                  <i class="right arrow icon"> </i>
          </div>
          <div className="ui right floated button" >
                  <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
             Prev
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows should be returning a `<tr>` at the top level, not a `<Form.Field>`.

Answer (score 0):

**for me adding this class worked.**

```
.ReactTable .rt-tbody .rt-td{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```